# Shell script to execute command if a file contain an ip adress

Tags: command-line, ip

Is there a way to verify a file and confirm existence of an IP address to execute a command upon ip add confirmation within the file?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick one that might work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" filename
case $? in
0) #If IPv4 Address found
    command to execute
;;
1) #If no IPv4 Address found
    No command needed here.
;;
esac
```

Comment: What about `999.999.999.999` (invalid IP, but matched)?

Comment: @waltinator Picky picky.  It was just a quick answer.  I'm not in the mood for anything else if the OP doesn't even ask a good question stating if they even tried anything at all.  Or add in requirements. ;)

Comment: Thank you Terrace, yes ive been trying my way around this and googling too. But im not very IT litterate and this is not really my sphere.
My issue is that some time my dynamic updater struggle through latency that is does not acquire an IP add before updating or the service providin the public ip lookup is oversaturted and give errors. I need some way to validate ip acquisition before proceeding with sending the new public ip to link everybody up.

Comment: checkip.dns.org, api.ipify.org … sometime result in errors

Comment: thank you walminator, yes been googling this too, https://www.putorius.net/grep-an-ip-address-from-a-file.html … but atually it is a real IP address being acquired and written to file. In my case it will definitely be a valid IP.